# Flashing stock LG firmware in GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, lg, stock-rom

I'm looking for a way to flash stock LG firmware for the LG M700DSK (Q6) in GNU/Linux.

I have tried running LG UP though Wine though it doesn't seem to open the installer for LG 8998 USB DLL. The LG UP installation itself went well. Is there anyway to flash these *.KDZ in Linux environment?